# What ports do I have to open for SMB sharing?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, samba

So I have a relatively simple Setup for a 5-people Company I am currently working on. This Setup includes:

- 1 Server
- 1 Router
- 3+ "Clients"

I want to open a Windows Network share on the Server, to be accessed by the Clients. The SMB protocol that I configured uses Port 445 at some Point.

Unfortunately the consumer electronics Router I work with blocks port 445 and 139 for security considerations (netbios attacks), without any option to disable the blocking.

I called the router vendor's support and the plan now is to manually open some ports for forwarding the traffic necessary for SMB correctly.

Now I tried to Forward incoming port 445 connections to the local network, but unfortunately the connection is still dead.

What ports do I need to open for the connection to the Network share to work correctly?

Comment: where in your network is your router? SMB cannot be effectively opened to the outside world (the clients wouldn't work, its not a port-based networking issue, but the way the protocol functions). The ports are `UDP\137-138` and `TCP\137,139,445`. Make sure `NetBIOS over TCP` is explicitly specified, and failing that, a WINS server may be helpful, but only do this if the router is in teh middle of your network. don't try to expose SMB over the internet. it just won't work. use an VPN or use web-safe technologies like SFTP\FTPS for remote file access.

Comment: "Don't try to expose SMB over the Internet" ... okay cancel that then. This is exactly what I am trying to do right now. I think I should really go for a SFTP-Based solution then. Thanks for the Swift Response :)

Comment: @Vogel612 I think Frank cleared this up very well as SMB over WAN is not recommended. To help more though what are you trying to achieve rather than 'accessed by clients'?

Comment: I want to expose a Directory to the users on their Client machine, where they can collaborate on Office-documents required for work. The ideal case would be to enable this to happen without any further necessity to interact with the Device, so an automatically connecting Network share was my first idea.

Answer (score 1):

#### SMB Ports [File Sharing]

- **Protocol:** tcp/udp
- **Ports:** 
   `137`: netbios-ns 
   `138`: netbios-dgm 
   `139`: netbios-ssn 
   `445`: smb-ds

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's either/or TCP/UDP for specific ports, not both: TCP: `139`, `445` | UDP: `137`, `138`